# AVMutableVideoComposition With CATextLayer Ending Up With No Text String

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, avassetexportsession, catextlayer

I'm trying to insert a text layer (`CATextLayer`) to a movie.  To begin with, let me insert a text layer (`CATextLayer`) to a wired `NSView` object like

```
let myLayer = CALayer()
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
let text = "Hello, Mr. Jordan.  How are you doing?"
let attributedString = MakeAttributedString.makeRegularCenterAttributedString(text: text, fsize: 64.0, color: NSColor.green) // A class function for creating an NSAttributedString
textLayer.string = attributedString
textLayer.isWrapped = true
textLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor
textLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0
textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 600, height: 200)
myLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
myView.layer?.addSublayer(myLayer) // myView is a wired `NSView` object laid over a wired `videoPlayer` object
```

Okay.  I get a `CATextLayer` inserted to the view.  Now, I try to do the same with `AVMutableVideoComposition`, creating a movie with with a `CATextLayer` object.

[image]

```
let parentLayer = CALayer()
parentLayer.isHidden = false
parentLayer.opacity = 1.0
parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1280.0, height: 720.0)
parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

let myLayer = CALayer()
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
let text = "Hello, Mr. Jordan.  How are you doing?"
let attributedString = MakeAttributedString.makeRegularCenterAttributedString(text: text, fsize: 64.0, color: NSColor.green)
textLayer.string = attributedString
textLayer.isWrapped = true
textLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor
textLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0
textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 600, height: 200)
myLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
parentLayer.addSublayer(myLayer)

let layerComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
layerComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
layerComposition.renderSize = self.frameSize
layerComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration)
let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
layerInstruction.setTransform(videoTrack.preferredTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)
instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction] as [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]
layerComposition.instructions = [instruction] as [AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol]

self.assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
self.assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
...
...
```

[image]

I get a background color of the text box.  But the text string is no show.  I can add audio and watermark images (`CALayer`) to a movie.  But the text string never appears.  How come I never end up with a text string?

**EDIT**

I have tested it under Sierra 10.12.6 with Xcode 9.2.  I have also tested it under High Sierra 10.13.4 with Xcode 9.4.1.  The text string is no show.  `CABasicAnimation` won't run with a movie track when the same animation with `NSView` works.  Setting a text string with `NSFont` or with an `NSAttributedString` won't make a difference.

Comment: It's an innocent mistake.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @matt Thanks.  I have done that as well.  I have exhausted all possibilities.  And I have made a bug report on Radur.

Comment: Nevertheless others have done this. Have you tried just copying some working code and running it? (Of course it may be that this feature works only on iOS, but that would be really weird...)

Comment: @matt Yes and no.  I have see many topics for iOS.  And I have written my macOS code based on those topics.  Many of them are written in Objective-C.  I have found several for Swift including the one at the following URL.  http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/05/21/swift-how-to-insert-animated-watermark-into-the-video-or-how-to-merge-two-videos/  I haven't tested my code for iOS.  There is little difference.

Comment: @ElTomato did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue and can't find anyone who's figure out how to do this on macOS anywhere.

Comment: @James Porter I don't remember what has solved the issue.  I remember having contacted TSI at Apple.